# Hide/Show block On Click

Tags: javascript, show-hide

When I click on the button, the corresponding list should be shown, but it doesn't work correctly.

> EGGS - Other list
>
> MEAT - List

If you immediately click on - Nothing happens.

If click again on the EGGS, and then on the MEAT - everything is ok.

Help please!

jsfiddle.net/Xtrance/5vgjr1m2/2/

Comment: Please describe more of **the desired behavior you want** + **what is the current situation**. "When I click on the button" - which button ? What does "EGGS - Other list" and "MEAT - List" mean ? What are you having in the DOM, what does each element do, what is the order of clicking, etc. At the moment, I am seeing 3 fields name "Eggs", some fields with cryptic number like "111", "222", etc. and some "other list" - I don't really know what each of them do or mean. Please give some more instructions as to how to navigate your app and steps to re-produce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because all your `input[name="radio-715"]` elements have `checked="checked"` attributes. Remove these attributes.